# Sorry but we are not able

Tags: error, database

[image]

I have tried to append a new contact
Contact saved
When I tried to search
this is the answer

Comment: Welcome to this Q/A site! Unfortunately your question is very hard to answer because you have not given enough details to tell what's going on. Please see https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/ to learn about how to find out those details (debug mode, server logs, etc) and post back here with more information.

Comment: Please check your civi log files for detailed error message

Answer (score 2):

You have experienced what is called, a CiviCRM fatal error, or as I like to say, yellow banner of death.

Please update your question with Civi version and CMS info too. Then Start here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/

Then share whats in the logs.